# angular round to the nearest integer using pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

what pipe do we use to round a number to a nearest dollar or integer for example 2729999.61 would be  2730000 .

Is there a way to do this on the angular template like using the number pipe ? like | number or

| number : '1.2-2'

Comment: are you wanting a angular solution or a c# one?

Comment: angula solution Sir

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs on DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe):

> The value's decimal representation is specified by the digitsInfo parameter, written in the following format:
>
> `{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}`

Of great importance as well:

> If the formatted value is truncated it will be rounded using the "to-nearest" method:

So, you want something like `number: '1.0-0'`:

```
// In your component:
myNumber = 2729999.61;

// And then in your template:
<p>Rounded number: {{ myNumber | number: '1.0-0' }}</p>
// will output 'Rounded number: 2,730,000'
```

If you want to format your numbers using some other criteria, creating a pipe to do so is easy. Here's an example pipe that just uses `Math.round`:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'customNumber' })
export class CustomNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, ...args: any[]) {
    return Math.round(value);
  }
}
```

... and to use it, make sure your pipe is imported as a declaration in your app module, then:

```
<!-- will output 'Rounded with custom pipe: 2730000' -->
<p>Rounded with custom pipe: {{ myNumber | customNumber }}</p>
```

Here's [a working stackblitz with both options](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wbsjew?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) to get you going.